# CSV Manipulation, cut value to new column

Tags: bash, csv

I have this CSV file with thousands of rows.

```
itemid;name;quantity;price;Weight;Images
45214;"Banana";351;2;1;"http://domain.com/images/image1.jpg,http://domain.com/images/image2.jpg,http://domain.com/images/image3.jpg"
```

Is there any easy way to add a column and cut the first image path (and remove the comma that would remain) and put it in to the new column.
So the result would be:

```
itemid;name;quantity;price;Weight;Images;Main_Image
45214;"Banana";351;2;1;"http://domain.com/images/image2.jpg,http://domain.com/images/image3.jpg";"http://domain.com/images/image1.jpg"
```

I use Debian and Bash

Comment: Sorry, added it. I use Debian and bash would be a great choice

Comment: This seems to just remove all the urls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this;

```
awk -F'[;,]' '{if(NR==1) print $1";"$2";"$3";"$4";"$5";"$6";Main_Image"; if(NR>1) print $1";"$2";"$3";"$4";"$5";\""$7","$8";"$6"\""}' yourCSV
```

test;

```
$ awk -F'[;,]' '{if(NR==1) print $1";"$2";"$3";"$4";"$5";"$6";Main_Image"; if(NR>1) print $1";"$2";"$3";"$4";"$5";\""$7","$8";"$6"\""}' test
itemid;name;quantity;price;Weight;Images;Main_Image
45214;"Banana";351;2;1;"http://domain.com/images/image2.jpg,http://domain.com/images/image3.jpg";"http://domain.com/images/image1.jpg"
```